# How create Tabs in a page of Joomla 2.5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I create Tabs in Page as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$tpath = $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template;
?>

<div id="tabs" >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Resize Image</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#tabs-2">Rotation Image</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#tabs-3">Crop Image</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">

    </div>
</div>
```

In simple PHP : it create Tabs OK. But In Joomla : it is not OK. (This code put in custom component)
Why ? How create Tabs in a page of Joomla 2.5?

Comment: where are you adding this code?

Comment: You will need to provide more details like where is this code, in a custom component, module or plugin or are you trying to put this in an article? Also what exactly do you mean by "it is not OK" — do you get an error message or does the content display without being turned into tabs or something else…

Comment: This code put in a custom component and It display all tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use special Joomla Tabs API

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('tabs.start', 'tab-group-id', array('useCookie'=>1)); ?>
<?php echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TAB1'), 'tab-id-1'); ?>

Tab 1 content

<?php echo JHtml::_('tabs.panel', JText::_('TAB2'), 'tab-id-2'); ?>

Tab 2 content

<?php echo JHtml::_('tabs.end'); ?>
```

Also you may use `sliders.start`, `sliders.panel` and `sliders.end` to create accordion.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing javascript to activate your tabs.

In the view of your custom component, you would add the following in your _prepareDocument function:

```
$tabsjs='$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
 });';
$this->document->addScriptDeclaration($tabsjs);
```

If I were you, I would also load my other javascripts and css into the head of the document like this:

```
$this->document->addscript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js');
JHTML::stylesheet('style.css', '/resources/demos/');
```